# Can I include a library stack in a LiveCode iOS project?

Tags: livecode

I've got a library stack that is included in a project.  The library is not a substack of the main stack, but is it possible to build for iOS without making it a substack?

```
start using stack "LC-Library"
LC_LIB_generate 30, true
```

I've tried using the 'Stacks' and 'Copy Files' panes in 'Standalone Application Settings'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either include it as a substack or try using the full path. Files included in the 'copy files' pane are placed in the engine folder which can be accessed using:

specialFolderPath("engine")

Comment: Thanks - working - and that saves me having to re-attach to each project when the library is updated

Comment: If they are placed next to the engine then on other platforms the engine can find them by name.